# What does strata mean here?

Tags: geology

What does strata mean here ?

> These consolidated layered **strata** are known as stratified rocks. The
>   strata vary in thickness and may be tilted or horizontal. The
>   sediments consist of loose particles of gravel, sand, silt in various
>   proportions hence are porous and permeable.

It comes from a chapter called *Materials of The Earth Crust-Rocks* from Frank Morden's Geography Class IX Part 1

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that "strata" here has a meaning different to its usual one? What are you looking for that you can't get by looking "strata" up in a dictionary, or by typing it into google?

Answer (score 3):

Strata always mean a collection of layers. A single layer is called a stratum. The plural of stratum is strata.